# Remove Heroku remote after setting it by default

Tags: git, heroku

I am going through octopress deployment to heroku

http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/heroku/

I did this

```
git config branch.master.remote heroku
```

without understanding the implications

its

```
# Set heroku to be the default remote for push/fetch
```

I tried

```
git remote rm origin
```

but the remote repo don't get removed. How do I remove the repo that I have set by default?

Answer (score 4):

Just set it back to `origin`:

```
$ git config branch.master.remote origin
```

Comment: I am getting this `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'` after trying your command and doing `git remote rm origin`

Comment: That means there's no remote called `origin`. Run `git remote -v` to see all remotes with their fetch and push urls.

Comment: Well that's because you deleted it earlier when you did `git remote rm origin`. You can add it back with `git remote add origin https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git` (assuming you cloned it from github).

Answer (score 0):

Try `git config --unset branch.master.remote` this should unset just the `git config branch.master.remote heroku` command without altering anything else.

If you want to point it elsewhere see @YuvalAdam answer.